# Using domXpath to search for anchor

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to search a html file or text for an anchor that has "friend" in its link. That is:
[zack is your friend](http://local.com)

Then when it matches an anchor, it should return the href attribute and the anchor (link). I have tried googling, but so far i can't understand domXpath and the other examples only search for the href attribute. I need the code to archieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath can do that. A xpath expression can contain conditions for the nodes. So lets start selecting all  elements anywhere in the document:

`//a`

Now, inside a condition fetch all subnodes (element and text) using `node()`, cast them to a `string()`, an check if that string `contains()` the substring "friend"

`//a[contains(string(node()), "friend")]`

Iterate over the nodes and read the data from them.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
  <a href="foo.html">zack is your friend</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//a[contains(string(node()), "friend")]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  var_dump(
    array(
      'href' => $node->getAttribute('href'),
      'text' => $node->textContent
    )
  );
}
```